# which approach is best to get instance of a Table in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am new to Cakephp and started with cake3.

A question arises on me is that which approach is the best from the performance sense to get an instance of a table in CakePHP-3.0 which is not a controller's default one  between loadModel or TableRegistry.

Such as:

```
1. $this->loadModel('Articles');
OR
2. TableRegistry::get('Articles');
```

I read Cake-Doc for [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models) and [TableRegistry](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object). Confusion comes from here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in a controller, it is better to use `loadModel()`. The reason is that it is easier to mock when doing unit testing.

It also sets the `$this->[MyTable]` variable according to the table that has be loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice explainations @José Lorenzo

Comment: Is there a prefered way between chaining models like `$this->MyTable1->MyTable2->find()` and loading the model via `loadModel();` ?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo, is that true that loadModel is slower than TableRegistry::get() as ndm is claiming at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400674/cakephp-loadmodel-vs-tableregistry?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: No, it is not true (in practical terms). It incurs in a an extra function call, but that could only be measured in nanoseconds